# Show the SKU in the dropdown of Configurable Products?

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product, dropdown-attribute

Possible this is a very simple task. But is it possible to add the SKUs of the Simple Products in the dropdown on the Configurable Products views?

There seem to be no option for doing this, so I assume it has to be programmed to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.
And here is why.
Let's say you have a configurable product with 2 configurable attributes. Size and color. 2 sizes (S, L) and 2 colors (Red, Blue).
So there are 4 combinations.
Let's say their SKUS are `RedS`, `RedL`, `BlueS`, `BlueL`

First you select a size then a color.
What SKU should you display in the dropdown for size?

There are 2 products for each size. For S there are `RedS` and `BlueS`.

You should be able to make it work for the last selecting attribute but a general way of doing this doesn't make sense.